# Stop propagation of javascript code when use it in bookmark

Tags: javascript

I have simple javascript code in bookmark url:

```
javascript:var descr=document.getElementById("descr");descr.value="some test here\nanother text";
```

I navigate to a page (www.something.com), click on bookmark button (saved with js code), the textbox seems to be filled BUT immediately that page disappeared and then on blank one (the browser's tab title is *javascript:....* (like above)) appears *some test here\nanother text* text.

I expected to fill that textarea and that it. How to write that javascript code in order to do not display result in a blank page ?

This issue happened on Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the whole Javascript inside an IIFE, and the JS should run properly without replacing the page:

```
javascript:(() => { var descr=document.getElementById("descr");descr.value="some test here\nanother text"; })();
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution.